# Undetected_chromedriver click method gets detected?wen scraping a site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

Using UC latest, if I driver.get the page and 'element.click() of safeclick' a button, the site detects I'm a bot and either captchas me or doesn't load the next page properly. But if I driver.get it and click the button manually, the site works fine.

Anyone know the best way to get around this? Is it something to do with mouse movements?